# unable to run ubuntu sdk cannot access lxd server

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-sdk, lxd

I have installed ubuntu-sdk and i am trying to run it but it says "The current user can not access the LXD server which is required for the Ubuntu SDK.
Make sure the user is part of the lxd group and restart the IDE.",why i cannot access lxd server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your user to the `lxd` group. The simplest way to this is the following:

`` sudo usermod -a -G lxd `whoami` ``

You will then need to log out and log back in again in order for the groups to be updated.

Comment: first if i run the command it says "lxd group does not exist",if i create lxd group and add the user and updating groups still i cannot run ubuntu-sdk.

Comment: That is strange, have you installed LXD, and is the server running? Try `sudo apt-get install lxd` After that make sure LXD server is running: `sudo service lxd start` Then you should be able to do a `sudo lxd init` the defaults should be fine for all the questions. Then you should be able to start ubuntu SDK IDE.

Comment: i am not able to run (sudo service lxd start)

Comment: A dependency job for lxd.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.

Comment: it says network unreachable (i am under a proxy server)

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with your proxy, unfortunately I can't help any more.. maybe you can find some useful information here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxd/+bug/1575386 good luck.