# ubuntu-sdk has lots of errors to start!

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I have installed ubuntu-sdk in x86_64, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Trusty.
When i execute ubuntu-sdk, there is an error:
"the current user can not access the LXD server which required for the Ubuntu SDK. Make sure the used is part of the lxd group and restart the IDE"

am@am:~$ whoami
am
am@am:~$ cat /etc/group
lxd:x:128:am
autopilot:x:129:am

Meanwhile i did not initialize lxd. I do not understand, what is lxd? 
am@am:~$ sudo lxd init
error: Unable to talk to LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket: connect: no such file or directory

What is zfs?

I want to develop application for Nexus 5, how I can do it by ubuntu-sdk?
ubuntu-sdk is installed for what hardware? Can it be used for Nexus 5?

Sorry to ask several questions but they are related to each other.....I will be appreciated for any answer in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to run ubuntu sdk cannot access lxd server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/835571/unable-to-run-ubuntu-sdk-cannot-access-lxd-server)

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu-SDK** is not meant for developing Android Apps. You need **Android-SDK** for developing Android apps for your Nexus.

See this link for installing: [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu)

**LXD** is a system-wide container daemon allowing the user to run containers that allows interaction with LXC software.

**ZFS** stands for Z file system. It allows good support for scaling and redundant storage.

As for a fix for your first issue, see this: [unable to run ubuntu sdk cannot access lxd server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835571/unable-to-run-ubuntu-sdk-cannot-access-lxd-server)

Comment: I have changed Android OS with UbuntuTouch. I have lxd group and my user is a member:
root@am:/home/am# lxd init
error: Unable to talk to LXD: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket: connect: no such file or directory
root@am:/home/am# service lxd start 
start: Unknown job: lxd

Comment: You have to do "sudo service lxd start" before initializing lxd.

Comment: I did with the following error:
am@am:~$ sudo service lxd start
start: Job failed to start

Comment: Try "sudo service lxd restart"